# Running high volumes of vital background task in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a scheduler, here are the functionalities that I want to achieve:

- Around 100+ tasks with varying time of execution depending on the schedule
- The task will be re-executed after 5 minutes if the initial execution failed.

I have no idea on how to implement it but my initial idea is to use cache expiration callbacks, but I'm not sure if it would be an optimal solution since the tasks that I might run are essential to my application. I want it to be robust but I have no idea where to start off.

Any good libraries/techniques that will allow me to achieve what I want to happen?

Comment: don't you want a windows service rather than an mvc application? Maybe certain things done by the MVC front-end app would trigger the service to do things, but for background automation you should hand off to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) is one of an excellent tools for running background processes. And now that I have used it in my application, I am a big fan of it.

It is very easy to implement and maintain. It can be easily scaled, can be hosted in any .net application type and it is a managed .net library.

What's more it is open source and free to use. (there is Pro version also available for additional feature)

And it's most compelling feature is out of the box dashboard for monitoring and have full control over the jobs.

Comment: Alright, I guess I will use that instead of rolling my own.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET isn't best suited to this sort of task, instead you'd likely be better using a windows service to perform your scheduled work.

Rather than reinventing the wheel to build a scheduler, or mucking around with annoying windows service projects that are nigh-on impossible to debug and work with, I'd recommend looking at [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) and the nifty [Topshelf.Quartz](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Topshelf.Integrations/) projects; the latter being specifically for scheduling.

Topshelf takes the hassle out of building, debugging and installing windows services, it's a great route to go down for this sort of thing!

---

## Note on Quartz

Quartz isn't entirely necessary for the scheduling component here, especially as it's likely to be **something else to learn**; you can always of course just stand up a timer in your service depending on how complex your scheduling requirements are, but Quartz with Topshelf will take care of a lot of stuff for you!